# Как сделать margin-top для col-xs строк bootstrap-а?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Вот такой вод код используется для отображения данных:

```
<div class="site-index">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x400" alt="..." />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x200" alt="..." />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250" alt="..." />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
         <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="..." />
        </a>
    </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
         <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="..." />
        </a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">
         <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="..." />
        </a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">
         <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="..." />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

получаем вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а мне нужен вот такой результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

который можно достичь вот таким кодом:

```
<div class="site-index">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/350x400" alt="...">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/350x200" alt="...">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/350x250" alt="...">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" style="margin-top: -50px;">
       <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="...">
        </a>
    </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
         <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="...">
        </a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-xs-4" style="margin-top: -30px;">
         <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="...">
        </a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-xs-4" style="margin-top: -50px;">
         <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="...">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

(добавил маргин топы)
а как решать эту проблему автоматически? полное решение мне не обязательно, нужно только направление(или алгоритм)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать https://masonry.desandro.com/ или поменять структуру вашего html кода

```css
.img-wrap {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="site-index">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-xs-4">
        <div class="img-wrap"><a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x400" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail" />
        </a></div>
        <div class="img-wrap"><a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail" />
        </a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-xs-4">
        <div class="img-wrap"><a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x200" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail" />
        </a></div>
        <div class="img-wrap"><a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail" />
        </a></div>
        <div class="img-wrap"><a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail" />
        </a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-xs-4">
        <div class="img-wrap"><a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail" />
        </a></div>
        <div class="img-wrap"><a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail" />
        </a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```